# Good quality food for Sphynx cat?

Tags: cats, diet, grooming

I have recently got a 4 year old Sphynx cat and I was looking for any recommendations for good quality food for him. I read that the food needs to be high in meat and preferably wet food so he gets a higher water intake. Also any recommendations for a shampoo that will be gentle for his skin?

Comment: I don't know about shampoos, but with cat food, generally one is as good as another, just so long as it isn't some fad food with ingredients that haven't been on the market for long, like don't give it grain-free food. I've seen many people recommending grain-free lately, but now it's under investigation by the FDA as a possible cause of canine dilated cardiomyopathy, and so people are also questioning whether it's any good for cats as well.

Comment: Where are you from? This will help us know what products are available where you live.

Comment: @Kai there's further research into that showing it's not the grain-free specifically, but the (often "exotic") non-meat protein sources swapped in to replace grain; in cat food, usually "grain free" is heavier in meat and doesn't use those non-meat sources, but label reading is always important: https://vetnutrition.tufts.edu/2018/11/dcm-update/

Comment: I think this is an on topic question. Sphynx cats have special needs